# Correct mathematical notation for negative of $2^n$

Tags: notation, convention

Given n is an positive integer,
I came across $-2^n$ and I was wondering if this is equal to

- case (1): $2^n$ for even values of n, and $-(2^n)$ for odd values of n
- or case (2): $-2^n$, no matter what value of n is

What is the correct notation for negative of $2^n$? $-2^n$ or $-(2^n)$, if I am looking to express negative of $2^n$? Is there any standard or widely accepted convention or notation for this? I looked into ISO 31-11 and ISO 80000-2 but couldn't understand.

Comment: Why would it be in the ISO standards? When we write $-2^n$, we mean exponentiate first, then glue the minus sign in front.

Comment: Then how do we express $(-2)^n$? There will be a redundancy there too. I guess my question is more of operator precedence. If (-) is considered as (-1*) then power takes precedence as you say, but if I say -1^-2 then it becomes -(1^-1)*2? Do you do 1^(-1) and then multiply by 2 or multiply by -1?

Comment: By far the most common convention (encoded in various abbreviations like PEMDAS, BODMAS, etc.) is to take the string $-2^n$ to mean $-(2^n)$ rather than $(-2)^n$.  In context, it is almost never the case that the two options are confusable.  In your own writing, you should add parentheses to give one of the completely unambiguous forms at any place you are worried a reasonable reader might not be able to understand.  There is no point in thinking about the "meaning" of expressions that are constructed intentionally to be ambiguous.

Comment: Correct and thank you all for clarifying the question. It seems I was pedantic and even symbolab takes $-2^n$ as per case (2) and the majority of the comments. The extra parenthesization is redundant and unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Case $(1)$ just amounts to "do you include the negative and hence use $(-2)^n$"?

This is obviously not the case. How does one handle expressions of the type, say,

$$10 - 2^n$$

In this sense, Case $(2)$'s interpretation is clearly used:

$$10-2^2 = 10-4=6 \qquad 10 - 2^3 = 10-8=2$$

Why should the convention differ if $10$ were replaced with $0$ instead, and hence become more compactly written as $-2^n$ (or arguably less ambiguously as $-(2^n)$)?

$-2^n$ is perfectly acceptable notation, and unambiguous (follow the order of operations), but for some a bit confusing. Those wanting to avoid it are welcome to write $(-1)(2^n)$ or any other such notation of their preference.

Comment: "Why should the convention differ..." because unary negative and binary minus aren't the same operation. It so happens that in this context the convention works out how you describe, but your phrasing makes it sound like you think a different convention for two uses of the same symbol would be universally unreasonable.